# ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations: customuser

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-migrations, unhandled-exception

I am trying to start a webpage using the Django framework. This is my first web development project.

After creating the project, I tried to start an app that utilizes customized users and registration with email validation using django-registration.

This is what happened when I ran `manage runserver`:

[image]

This is what ***models.py*** file contains:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name=_("Username")) 
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, verbose_name=_("Email Address"))
    favorite_animal = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_("Favorite Animal"))
```

Comment: Please put the error message/stacktrace as text not as an image so it's better search engine indexable and readable by screen reader etc.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You haven't run `manage.py makemigrations customuser` to create the migrations for your CustomUser app.

Also, you haven't run any of the existing migrations - you should do `manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 19):

Run the following commands

1. `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. `python manage.py migrate`

This solved my error.
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 5):

For me makemigrations was the one throwing the error which was super annoying. Finally I realized I had deleted all the migration files, but you have to delete the migrations folder as well! Otherwise you'll get this error.

Answer (score 0):

The default Django user model is different from the customized user model of course, that's why I did next:

1. I deleted the database (in my case it was a studying project and of course, I could afford it myself)
2. run 'python manage.py makemigrations'
3. run 'python manage.py migrate'

It's crucial to realize, that you should design your user model at the beginning of the development of your project because during production it would be a very big problem for applying these migrations.

Answer (score -3):

try drop database, run again makemigrations and after migrate.

Comment: You should add a scenario where this is required boss... It's a high level solution where all else have failed